# Roundcube and PHP 5.6

Tags: php, roundcube

Since upgrading my server to the latest version of Debian, roundcube (1.2.3) no longer works. It turns out this is because the new versions of PHP (5.6) now check to see if it is a valid certificate. Based on looking into this further I have found out that I can add the following lines to my config.inc.php file:

```
$config['imap_conn_options'] = array(
    'ssl' => array(
      'verify_peer' => false,
      'verify_peer_name' => false
     )
 );


$config['smtp_conn_options'] = array(
    'ssl' => array(
       'verify_peer' => false,
       'verify_peer_name' => false
     )
 );
```

I also have the following setting:

```
$config['default_host'] = 'tls://localhost';
```

I am using this roundcube install for multiple domains so did not want to put a specific domain in here. I also do not want to pay for a certificate so wanted to set verify_peer to false.

When I try to sign in it says "login failed". syslog gives the following error:

```
Feb  8 10:55:19 server1 dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 2 secs): user=<office>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, TLS, session=<D+K0ugdIigAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
```

I am wondering if this method=PLAIN is throwing things off if it is supposed to be using TLS.

I have dovecot/postfix set up on the backend with virtual users/domains/aliases in a mysql database. I have tried sending a message to these addresses and they do get redirected to the correct alias email address. So, as far as I know dovecot and postfix are working correctly.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. I was not specifying the domain with the username. I had to update my roundcube config.inc.php file with the following line:

```
$config['username_domain'] = '%d';
```

This allowed me to use roundcube from any of my domains (mail.domain1.com, mail.domain2.com, etc) without specifying the domain name in the Username box.